# package expected, got syntax

Tags: protocol-buffers, protoc, goland

My Goland IDE on Mac doesn't understand -> syntax = "proto3" do you know why?

package expected, got syntax

Either I put the syntax before or after the package declaration, it doesn't change nothing...

My example.proto file looks like

```
syntax = "proto3";

package main;

service Greeter {
rpc login (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
rpc logging (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
}

message HelloRequest{
string ID=1;
}

message HelloReply{
string response=1;
}
```

I already tried this solution but nothing happened the error remains as it is :

Solution -

- Close Goland
- Remove the .idea folder -> rm -rf .idea
- reopen the project with Goland

Anyone has any other solution please help.

Comment: Are you sure the file is named `example.proto` and not `something.go`?

Comment: yes I m 100% sure @icza

Comment: And are you sure this is the file that triggers the compilation error? What if you delete this file? Pleas post the complete error message (complete compiler output).

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you either associated all `.proto` files with the Go extension or just that particular file.

To check it, go to `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types | Go` and check the registered patterns there.

Comment: Just that file.
These are the registered patterns

* .as
* .es
* .js2

Comment: Those are not the patterns for Go, scroll down in the list until you see `Go ` and check there please.